# Data binding for listview in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to populate listview with database table in xamarin forms app
I am getting null pointer exception

**Below is XAML for listview**

```
<ListView x:Name="_listView"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding itemsInList}" 
          Grid.Column="0" 
          Grid.Row="0" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding Name}"  Grid.Column="0"   Grid.Row="0" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Below is xaml.cs(code behind)**

```
public List <ServiceProvider> itemlist;
public List <ServiceProvider> itemsInList 
{
   get {return itemlist;}
}
protected override void OnAppearing() 
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   ExpensesDatabase dbcon = new ExpensesDatabase(completePath);
   itemlist = dbcon.GetItems(completePath);
   // _listView.ItemsSource = itemlist;
}
```

**Below is db file**

```
public class ExpensesDatabase 
{
    readonly SQLiteConnection database;
    public ExpensesDatabase(string dbPath) 
    {
        database = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
        database.CreateTable < ServiceProvider > ();
    }
    public List < ServiceProvider > GetItems(string dbPath) 
    {
        return database.Table < ServiceProvider > ().ToList();
    }
}
```

Data is not displayed in listview

Comment: Use ObservableCollection instead of simple list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `ListView` to automatically update as items are added, removed and changed in the underlying list, you'll need to use an `ObservableCollection`. `ObservableCollection` is defined in `System.Collections.ObjectModel` and is just like List, except that it can notify `ListView` of any changes:

```
 public ObservableCollection<ServiceProvider> itemsInList { get; set; }
```

Then make sure you have set the right `bindingContext` and initialized the `ObservableCollection`:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            itemsInList = new ObservableCollection<ServiceProvider>();

            BindingContext = this;

        }
```

I write a sample to test and it works on my side, you can have a look at the full code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceProvider> itemsInList { get; set; }


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        itemsInList = new ObservableCollection<ServiceProvider>();

        BindingContext = this;

    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        itemsInList.Add(new ServiceProvider() { Name= "a"});
    }
}

public class ServiceProvider : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string name;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ServiceProvider()
    {

    }

    public String Name
    {
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask me any question if you still can't solve it.

Comment: can u please post xaml used?

Comment: @GayatriGovilkar I use the same xaml as you. I did not change anything.

Comment: @GayatriGovilkar 1. use ObservableCollection instead of List. 2 Check if there is data in itemlist in onAppearing 3. You can bind the itemSource to itemlist directly instead of itemsInList 4. make sure your ServiceProvider  model implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: @GayatriGovilkar You missed the ViewCell tag under DataTemplate, the code should be:         <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Name of Service" />
            <ListView x:Name="_listView" ItemsSource="{Binding itemsList}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>

Comment: @GayatriGovilkar Can you please mark/accept this answer so that we can help more people with same problem?